# Pros and Cons regarding extended use of branches

Tags: branch, process, code-organization, configuration-management

I want to be able to choose the right branching strategy for most thinkable situations and organizations. So I'm looking for a extensive list of positive and negative effects of extending the use of code repository branches in a development organization.

Please only post one *pro* **or** one *con* in each post, so that the voting system can help rank the feedback somewhat.

Comment: You can't format the responses this way. People should answer however they choose too, and then others will comment on it, so there is a dialog. Rather than limiting people in how much they can say.

Comment: People can say how much they want about a certain pro or con. I just want to prevent ambiguity. I think the subject matter should be ranked, rather than a certain person's comprised view of pros and cons.

Answer (score 4):

Pro: By keeping latest deployed version in trunk, small fixes can be rolled out quickly without extensive testing of the latest development version.

Answer (score 3):

**Pro:** Developers can work more freely in tighter iterations without stepping on eachother's feet.

Answer (score 3):

Pro: if you have many branches you'll be pushed to adopt a modern DVCS (my experience is with Mercurial but I hear git or Bazaar are also good) rather than stay with a traditional centralized system (like, say, svn).

Answer (score 3):

**Pro:** Branches can be used to facilitate 'what-if' scenario's in trying out new code. At the end a decision can be made to merge the new feature or to abandon it.

Answer (score 2):

**Con (and it can be a big one):** Merging back at a point in the future. The longer the duration and the greater the deviation of code base, the harder your life will be. My advice: think very carefully about branching and ensure you only do it when necessary and consider the effort involved in merging at a later date should it be required.

Comment: maybe devide into two answers?

Comment: This is a limitation of the older version control systems without easy branching and merging. Try using Git, Mercurial or other similar ones.

Answer (score 2):

**Con:** Having too many branches in the air at the same time and you start forgetting where things where commited, where changes have been made etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Con**: Merge nightmare.

Comment: Yes, if using underperforming tools like Sourcesafe, TFS or Subversion. Less so with a DVCS like git or Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

**Con:** Greater learning threshold for junior developers.

Answer (score 0):

**Pro**: Each update is independant from the others, so work can be parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

**Con**: someone **has** to manage the branch(es) and keep on top of things. In most teams this falls by the way-side.

Answer (score 0):

**Pro:** Greater flexibility in diverging code for the purpose of simultaneously developing on or supporting multiple streams of work.